# Calculate image size of an object from real size

Tags: opencv, geometry

I try to place a car(2D image of the car) on the road in the image, but I need to calculate a car size in pixels for the [chosen horizontal position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64qh7.jpg). I've found this
[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DABze.png). It has object height(mm) which I need, but I don't have a distance to object(mm). Is there any way to calculate the distance from the camera to the horizontal line where car placed?

I knew camera matrix(fx,fy,cx,cy) and the real size of the car

Answer (score 4):

If you know the size of the car, then it is possible to know the distance to it. However, you also need the information from the sensor size and focal position. 
As depicted in this image [image: Camera lenses], the distance D can be deduced from d, h and H by a simple conversion: d/D = h/H. Therefore, D=(H*d)/h. With h the size of the sensor in pixel, d the focal distance in mm and H the object size in pixels. D is the distance to the object in mm.